How to infer the cordinate system dynamically from a wkt point, for create buffers?
What about if you have a multiple point of the world? How can infer the cordinate system dynamically from a place in Python, for example Mexico, Brazil, Chile, Canada, etc.?
The goal is to create a buffer in meters for many country points data in wkt.
Actually I use Sedona and Spark for this, but the EPSG code of data point
is needed pass manually to calculate the buffer in meters and then reproject to EPSG:4326, this is little imprecise (I know that this way cannot obtain a 100% acurracy vs a PostgreSQL PostGIS SQL, but I think what could be better).

Your title asks how to "infer" a coordinate system, but the Question body seems to ask about choosing one. I suspect your concerns about "100% accuracy" are unwarranted (not possible anyway, but anything over 181 geodetic vertices is going to be really close). You just need to create a service that generates a geodetic buffer.

Have you tried this?

i'll test it ! looks like the tool what needed

yees its works you are a genius!!!  thanks so much !! @BERA
